# Manipulating .sql files

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I'm new to SQL and I'm tasked with transferring data from a `Drupal DB` to a `Wordpress DB`; 
I was wondering what the best way to do this would be. I know that there are built in MySQL functions in PHP but I was wondering if I could manipulate the `raw .sql` files with Python? 
I can't seem to find sql parsing functions similar to the ones available for xml or csv 
(eg. dataXMLFilter, csv.DictReader etc.).
 Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Is there not a tool for this complete task already?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content)

Comment: Yes, whatever you do, the core of your operations will be carried out as MySQL commands, see here http://blondish.net/how-to-convert-drupal-to-wordpress/ It does not really matter which 'interface' you use to fire these commands. The post suggests you actually do it in a phpmyadmin environment, but that is only a question of preference.

Comment: A large part of the DB is custom and we're going to clean some of the old data up in the process. If the operations will have to be carried out as MySQL commands I'll use PHP's MySQLi library. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ppeterka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667004/ppeterka) already said, there are tools to [import content from Drupal into Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal).

The general approach for this kind of problem is:

Export the data in a generic format (XML, CSV), convert it into a target generic format (again XML or CSV) and then import that target format into the target database.

This approach allows you to do many different conversions without being limited by your database (like missing foreign keys during the transformation).

If you have transformation steps that could benefit from SQL statements, then you can import some of the data into a temporary conversion database, work on it and then export the results for further processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I ended up rebuilding the database custom using MySQLi to clean up some of the DB but your answer helped set me in the right direction.